# How to create a Power BI pivot table without drill-down?

Tags: pivot-table, powerbi

I have data of the following form for several categories and years.  The data is too large for Import so I am using DirectQuery.

```
Id  Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    Year    Value
1   A   X   Q   2000    1
2   A   X   R   2000    2
3   A   Y   Q   2000    3
4   A   Y   R   2000    4
5   A   X   Q   2000    1
6   A   X   R   2000    2
7   A   Y   Q   2000    3
8   A   Y   R   2000    4
9   A   X   Q   2001    1
10  A   X   R   2001    2
11  A   Y   Q   2001    3
12  A   Y   R   2001    4
13  A   X   Q   2001    1
14  A   X   R   2001    2
15  A   Y   Q   2001    3
16  A   Y   R   2001    4
```

I would like construct a pivot table similar to what can be done in Excel.

```
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    2000    2001
A   X   Q   2   2
A   X   R   4   4
A   Y   Q   6   6
A   Y   R   8   8
```

I tried this with the *Matrix* option by; placing columns Cat1, Cat2, and Cat3 in the Rows, placing Year in the Columns, and placing Value in the Values. Unfortunately, this produces a hierarchical view.

```
Cat1    2000    2001
A       20      20
 X      6       6
   Q    2       2
   R    4       4
 Y      14      14
   Q    6       6
   R    8       8
```

How do I get the simpler Excel pivot table view of the data instead of the hierarchical view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to get the row headers to repeat like in your example, but if you go to Format > Row headers > Stepped layout and toggle that off, then your matrix should change from what you are seeing (below left) to something closer to what you want (below right).

[image: Stepped Layout]